# blender 2.8 как развернуть окно 2d вида

Tags: blender

в 3д максе можно было любое из 4 окон развернуть на все окно. в блендере могу только окно 3д вида. можно ли остальные разворачивать?

Comment: Ctrl+Пробел разворачивает абсолютно любое окно — только не забудьте навести курсор мыши на нужное

Comment: @andreymal не знаю как у вас, а у меня эти клавиши скрывают/открывают панель инструментов справа и полоску кадров внизу, и не колышет на каком окне стоит курсор

Comment: Ну тогда Ctrl+Alt+Q жмите, чтобы выключить/включить четырёхоконный 3D-вид

Comment: @andreymal это мне известно. но мне нужно увеличить ДРУГИЕ окна. в блендере такое возможно?

Comment: Другие это какие? Когда я открываю у тебя blender 2.8, у меня Ctrl+Пробел прекрасно разворачивает всё, на что я наведу курсор. Если у вас что-то не разворачивается — расскажите что и где

Comment: @andreymal https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZNDL.png вот эти другие окна, quad view так сказать. навожу стрелку на каждое из них, нажимаю ctrl + пробел - ничего не выходит

Comment: Почему в вопросе про 2.8, а скриншот из 2.71? Поленились сами скриншот сделать? Как я уже написал выше, у меня этот quad view по нажатию Ctrl+Пробел замечательно разворачивается на всё окно, а по нажатию Ctrl+Alt+Q можно выключить четырёхоконный вид и получить один большой обзор на всё окно. С чем у вас возникают проблемы — непонятно

Comment: @andreymal я сейчас не за своим компом, скрин привел для примера, не думаю что версия имеет большое значение, суть проблемы я объяснил

Comment: @andreymal "один большой обзор на всё окно" - у вас какое окно разворачивается? 3д вида? мне нужно 2д вида, одно из них

Comment: Переключите 3д вид в нужный 2д вид нажатием Num1/Num3/Num7/Num9 как обычно

Comment: (впрочем, странно, что эти клавиши довольно трудно найти в документации Blender, тем не менее https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

В Blender можно развернуть окно комбинацией клавиш **CTRL+Up** и соответственно свернуть  **CTRL+Down**